# ListView.EmptyView not displaying when ListAdapter is empty

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an Activity that Extends ListActivity to display some search results. Everything is working fine except when there are no results (the adapter is empty) I can't get the EmptyView to display text depicting this. See code below.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var description = Intent.GetStringExtra("Description");
        var partResults = this.partsClient.GetPartsSearchResults(description);
        this.results = partResults;
        var textView = new TextView(ListView.Context);
        textView.Text = "No Results...";
        this.ListView.EmptyView = textView;
        this.ListAdapter = new PartsListAdapter(this, results);

    }
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code as to why the text "No Results..." won't display when the adapter results are empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the following **before** you call `setEmptyView()`:

```
((ViewGroup)this.ListView.getParent()).addView(textView);
```

This is because EmptyView works by toggling the visible / invisible state of an already existing view on the layout, it won't add that view to the layout for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Empty TextView as

```
this.listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyElement));
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either, I tried using the standard views (ie a listview with id list and a textview with id empty) I'm at a loss because according to the documentation (as you pointed out) this should work...